# Azure Active Directory: Retrieve Exposed Client Applications

Tags: azure, authentication, oauth-2.0

Is there a way, though the Azure CLI or the Microsoft Graph API to retrieve the list of client (ids), that an app registration is exposed to.

I was successful at using the Azure CLI, Azure Powershell Tools and the Microsoft Graph API to retrieve the API permissions of an app registration, but I only get the defined scopes for said app registration, not the exposed static consumers. Is this at all possible?

To be more precise: If you go to the Azure Portal an got to "Active Directory" > "App Registrations" > "Expose an API" then there is a list under "Authorized client applications". This is the list I would like to retrieve.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the beta endpoint of MS Graph API, it doesn't seem like those are available.
So for now your only option is to get that info from the portal.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/application?view=graph-rest-beta

Comment: Hm, sad. I was able to configure one apps access to another app through both function ("Expose API" and "API Permissions"). Is there a resource somewhere, that explains the difference?

Comment: I don't remember if those are in docs, but adding authorized client application will allow that app to use those scopes without consent being asked. If you add them without that to the API Permissions on the client app, it'll ask for consent from the users (unless you click Grant admin consent on the API Permissions page).